# Unable to RDP to a remote server -- my user just stopped working

Tags: rdp

We have three servers hosted by Rackspace.  I am using mRemoteNG to connect to all three.  Historically, no problem.  I could RDP to all three no problem.  Then yesterday, one of them stopped letting me in, and it gives me this error:

```
RDP disconnected!  
Because of a protocol error, this session will be disconnected. 
Please try connecting to the remote computer again. 
Error code 3334.
```

I have tried to connect via the standard Windows RDP client.  It just fails with no error. So it's not just the mRemoteNG client.

There are other users on the same server who can RDP to it just fine with their own user.  But nobody can RDP to that box with my user.  We also created new users, and none of them work for anyone either.

I have googled the snot out of this, and the ONLY fix I can find is to set mRemoteNG to use LARGEADDRESSAWARE.  According to what I've read, the steps for this are as follows:

1. Use Visual Studio command prompt (the normal windows one won't work). Make sure to run as administrator
2. Enter the following command: editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE "C:\Program Files (x86)\mRemoteNG\mRemoteNG.exe"

Done.

But, when I do that, I am told: fatal error cannot open file C:\Program Files (x86)\mRemoteNG\mRemoteNG.exe

**EDIT:**

Remote server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: First, lets fix your RDP error, flush your userprofile on that server would be my first test, in case of a corrupt profile. Please edit your question to include your server OS.

Comment: ok, I'll edit the OP.  In the mean time, what does "flush" mean.  Delete and re-create?

Comment: Yes, delete it the good way (https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/2462308) and let the system recreate it at your next login

Comment: ?  The good way?!?  I only know of one way :-)

Comment: I pasted a link :) as in pre 2008 old admin used to simply delete the user folder, thus now you will miss registry key too :)

Comment: I just got frozen out of an RDP session that would still let us in.  And when I tried to re-connect, it gave the same error.  I think this machine might need a reboot

Answer (score 2):

Ok, problem solved.

We got onto the remote server as another user, went into:

Start > Admin Tools > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Services Manager

From there, I killed the session for my user.  Then, when I tried again, I was able to RDP in.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this network issue that, along with some other unrelated errors, appeared to be caused by having multiple network connections active simultaneously, including both WiFi and an Ethernet cable. I noticed a 'No internet' indication on my LAN connection, while the WiFi was connected to a completely different network outside of my LAN. This setup initially allowed me to use RDP to connect to a remote server within my LAN, but the connection would eventually fail with an error. I also experienced problems using TeamViewer.

Once I eliminated the multiple network connections, leaving only a single connection active, the problem was resolved.